# Check broken links in datalist

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

i have datalist having column of _File which hold file name to download

i want to hide those records which have broken links (dos't have file on blabla location)

i try to use this

```
public bool RemoteFileExists(string url)
{
    try
    {
        //Creating the HttpWebRequest
        System.Net.HttpWebRequest request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url) as System.Net.HttpWebRequest;
        //Setting the Request method HEAD, you can also use GET too.
        request.Method = "HEAD";
        //Getting the Web Response.
        System.Net.HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as System.Net.HttpWebResponse;
        //Returns TRUE if the Status code == 200
        return (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
    catch
    {
        //Any exception will returns false.
        return false;
    }
}
```

ASPX

```
<% if (RemoteFileExists("www.*****/" + Eval("_File").ToString() + ".pdf"))
                       { 
                    %>
                    <tr>

                        <td style="background-color: white; border-bottom: 1px solid #dbdbdb" width="700">
                            <div style="font-size: 16px; width: 600px; margin-top: 2px; display: block; float: left; color: black;"><%# Eval("Title") %></div>
                            <div style="font-size: 11px; width: 600px; display: block; float: left; margin-top: -3px; color: gray;"><%# Eval("Department") %>, <%# Eval("Program") %>, <%# Eval("Semester") %></div>
                            <a style="float: right; font-size: 12px; padding-left: 18px; padding-right: 5px; margin-right: -4px; margin-top: 0px" target="_blank" class="downloadIcon" href='<%# "1913/" + Eval("_File") + ".pdf" %>'>Download</a></td>

                    </tr>
                    <%
                        }

                    %>
```

i got this error == Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control

***I got solution basicaly url text is wrong, need to enter http:// as well.***

```
<div runat="server" visible=<%# RemoteFileExists("http://www.***/" + Eval("_File").ToString() + ".pdf") %>>
                    <tr>

                        <td style="background-color: white; border-bottom: 1px solid #dbdbdb" width="700">
                            <div style="font-size: 16px; width: 600px; margin-top: 2px; display: block; float: left; color: black;"><%# Eval("Title") %></div>
                            <div style="font-size: 11px; width: 600px; display: block; float: left; margin-top: -3px; color: gray;"><%# Eval("Department") %>, <%# Eval("Program") %>, <%# Eval("Semester") %></div>
                            <a style="float: right; font-size: 12px; padding-left: 18px; padding-right: 5px; margin-right: -4px; margin-top: 0px" target="_blank" class="downloadIcon" href='<%# "1913/" + Eval("_File") + ".pdf" %>'>Download</a></td>

                    </tr>
                        </div>
```

Comment: So what happens when you execute your code? Does it return an error?

Comment: yes i got this error == Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control.

Comment: Try debugging your code and set some breakpoints to see exactly where the issue is happening. The particular error message above does not seem to have anything to do with your RemoteFileExists function.

Comment: Debugging showing error on Line 20: <% if (RemoteFileExists("www.***/Misc/1913/" + Eval("_File").ToString() + ".pdf"))

Comment: So basically the error messaging is telling you it can't evaluate the "_File" expression because it is not used in the context of the databound control. Can you show more code? how are you binding your data to the table?